# # as abbreviation of "Number of"/"Count of"

Tags: publications, paper-submission, physics

I'm writing a scientific paper, and I seen a lot of times the abbreviation # for 'number of' or similar, for example if we are counting events, I seen expressed the results as,

**# type1 = 100**,    **# type2 = 140** ...

Is a formal way to express it? or is colloquial, I could not find this information explicitly nowhere.

Comment: In math, some people use #A, others |A| to denote the cardinality of the set A. I would assume that a vast majority of people in related fields would understand this symbol in that way.

Comment: Why not assign a proper variable name $N_i$ to type $i$? I have no doubt people will understand the style you propose, but it wouldn't be my choice and the syntax is not as well defined as a formal mathematical statement. I realize LaTeX is not supported in the comments here, what I mean with `$$` is to use mathematical typesetting like the one available in LaTeX.

Comment: As you say, it's quite common to see # used for e.g. detector counts in papers. It's a rather self-descriptive notation in that it's not necessary to formally introduce a variable. However, it can become a bit messy if it's a quantity included in formulas or repeated several times, in which case rhermans' suggestion would be the preferred approach.

Comment: What are you asking? If it's OK to do? (Personally, I'd write ": " not "=", but that's not what you asked)

Comment: Possibly related to https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90816/